# How to I solve formatting problem on vscode for react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I've started watching a React Tutorial.

And I do have problem, vscode doesn't format styled consts.
Also if I want to write fs14 or fs It doesn't recommand me anything.

```
const Container = styled.div`
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
position: relative;
background-color: coral;

`

const Arrow = styled.div`

    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff7f7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: ${(props) => props.direction === "left" && "10px"};
    right: ${(props) => props.direction === "right" && "10px"};
    margin: auto;
`
```

After I format the file, the Container remains the same.
Also If I want to write fs/fs14 for example it doesn't recommand my font-size => font-size: 14;

Help please? :D

Comment: Your post title is not very understable to searching users. It is very general. I hope the editor of your post corrects this.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the styled components extension and see if that solves the problem https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components